# CS0103 - The name does not exist in the context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently following the microsoft visual C# step by step, ninth edition lesson. I came across an issue that states the name does not exist in the context. I did some research and found the example of how to solve the problem but still have no luck. Should I ignored it and continue or do some more research?

here is the script was causing the issue.

```
       (division, remainder) = divide(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);
```

Code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calculateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int calculatedValue = 0;

        try
        {
            int leftHandSide = System.Int32.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
            int rightHandSide = System.Int32.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);


            if (addition.IsChecked.HasValue && addition.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calculatedValue = addValues(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);
                showResult(calculatedValue);
            }
            else if (subtraction.IsChecked.HasValue && subtraction.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calculatedValue = subtractValues(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);
                showResult(calculatedValue);
            }
            else if (multiplication.IsChecked.HasValue && multiplication.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calculatedValue = multiplyValues(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);
                showResult(calculatedValue);
            }
            else if (division.IsChecked.HasValue && division.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                int division, remainder;
                (division, remainder) = divide(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);

                result.Text = $"{division} remainder {remainder}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception caught)
        {
            expression.Text = "";
            result.Text = caught.Message;
        }
    }

    private int addValues(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
    {
        expression.Text = $"{leftHandSide} + {rightHandSide}";
        return leftHandSide + rightHandSide;
    }

    private int subtractValues(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
    {
        expression.Text = $"{leftHandSide} - {rightHandSide}";
        return leftHandSide - rightHandSide;
    }

    private int multiplyValues(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
    {
        expression.Text = $"{leftHandSide} * {rightHandSide}";
        return leftHandSide * rightHandSide;
    }

    private int divideValues(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
    {
        expression.Text = $"{leftHandSide} / {rightHandSide}";
        return leftHandSide / rightHandSide;
    }

    private int remainderValues(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
    {
        expression.Text = $"{leftHandSide} % {rightHandSide}";
        return leftHandSide % rightHandSide;
    }

    private void showResult(int answer) => result.Text = answer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In what like is the problem? what have you tried in order to solve it?

Comment: BTW your divide is an integer divide (for example 1/2 = 0) - be sure that is what you are looking for

Comment: Never ignore errors. Fix errors. You code won't compile with errors anyway. So... does this answer your question?

Comment: sorry

else if (division.IsChecked.HasValue && division.IsChecked.Value)
                {
                    int division, remainder;
                    (division, remainder) = divide(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);

                    result.Text = $"{division} remainder {remainder}";
                }
the divide does not exist if this help where the problem start

Comment: @Sebastien - please edit question to include this important piece of information

Comment: Eelgonzo thanks but i still new to this so my problem still isnt solve because i can't figure what am I doing wrong with the "divide" since it isn't in the context which I do not understand. and the CS0103, i did not understand how it can help me fix the problem

Comment: thanks gilad green, i edited so hopefully that will explain where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your divide section you are calling a `divide` function that is supposed to return a tuple with two values. No where in your code you define such a method. Instead you defined `divideValues` and `remainderValues`. You can change it to:

```
else if (division.IsChecked.HasValue && division.IsChecked.Value)
{
    int division = divideValues(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);
    int remainder = remainderValues(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);

    result.Text = $"{division} remainder {remainder}";
}
```

Notice that by calling these functions one after the other you will only see the `expression.Text` of the `remainderValues`.

---

In addition, you can also write a new function:

```
private (int division, int remainder) divide(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
{
    expression.Text = $"division: {leftHandSide} % {rightHandSide}, remainder: {leftHandSide} % {rightHandSide}";
    return (leftHandSide / rightHandSide, leftHandSide % rightHandSide);
}
```

and then call as before:

Comment: @Sebastien - I would recommend you have a look at the How To Ask and Take The Tour pages of StackOverflow so next time you write a question that is simpler to understand.

In addition if this helped you solve the problem you could mark this question as solved. If you found the answer informative too and want to you can also upvote it :)

Comment: that new function you wrote... i tried using the VS suggestion and it added that into the program but i did not know how i was suppose to write statement.

p.s. I went ahead and tried that new function and it also work.